# Read data from Cloud Storage using blob.download_as_string

Tags: python, numpy, google-cloud-storage

I am reading a `.ecg` file that is present in the `Google Cloud Storage` and the data stored in the file is used for further calculation.

```
client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket(data['bucket'])
blob = bucket.get_blob(data['name'])
data = blob.download_as_string()
```

The result of the download is a bytearray looks like this 
`bytearray(b'-0.14\n-0.14\n-0.14\n-0.14\n-0.14\n-0.14\n-0.14\n-0.14\n-0.12\n-0.14\n-0.14\n-0.15\n-0.16\n-0.15\n-0.16\n-0.17\n-0.18\n-0.18\n-0.17\n-0.15\n-0.17\n-0.18\n-0.19\n-0.18\n-0.15\n-0.14\n-0.15\n-0.19\n-0.20\n-0.23\n-0.23\n-0.24\n-0.25\n-0.26\n-0.28\n-0.28\n-0.28\n-0.27\n-0.26\n-0.27\n-0.28\n-0.29\n-0.29\n-0.29\n-0.29\n-0.28\n-0.29\n-0.30\n-0.28\n-0.28\n-0.28\n-0.28\n-0.28\n-0.30\n-0.29\n-0.30\n-0.28\n-0.29\n-0.30\n-0.32\n-0.32\n-0.34\n-0.36\n-0.39\n-0.39\n-0.41\n-0.46\n-0.48\n-0.48\n-0.42\n-0.33\n-0.22\n-0.07\n0.12\n0.38\n0.62\n0.78\n0.84\n0.77\n0.52\n0.17\n-0.17\n-0.36\n-0.43\n-0.42\n-0.37\n-0.33\n-0.33\n-0.34\n-0.3`

I need to convert them into a `numpy array`, but on using `cloud_file_data = np.frombuffer(data, dtype=np.float)`, I observed that the data has changed. It looks like this `[45. 48. 46. ... 48. 46. 51.]`

How do I resolve this?

Comment: I assuming it considers `\n` as a valid byte instead of newline.

Comment: are you sure you are getting a bytearray in this line `data = blob.download_as_string()`. from what I know, this method return a byte object and not a bytearray. check [here](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.download_as_string). can you double check that?